# Hibernate mapping with soft deletes and "cascades"?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I'm currently trying to map a sql table with hibernate using a hbm.xml file. Usually, when mapping a class we add a clause 'where="deleted=0"' to the class tag.

However, I now need to map a table A that is essentially a property of table B. That is, if B.delete == 1, then the corresponding A row is "deleted" as well.

Thing is, we don't have a "deleted" column on table A, rather deferring this flag to table B.

Is it possible to map this clause to the definition of class A? Or will I need to explicitly do a join for every query?

Comment: so you have one to one mapping? and you want to consider A is deleted if B is deleted - but not do a join? how is that possible even logically without jpa? and why not put deleted flag in A, that would be clean design from db point of view

Comment: I mean do do some sort of "join" in the mapping file itself to simplify each query. It's also not a one to one mapping,  it's a many to one mapping. I can see the benefits of adding a deleted flag to A itself but,  wondering if it's possible to do this without the redundant deleted flag that already exists in B.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using eclipselink, this may do the trick

https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Mapping/Additional_Criteria

e.g.

```
@Entity
@AdditionalCriteria("this.b.isDeleted=0")
public class A {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

May not be the most efficient, in fact it most definitely isn't, but in case anyone else was interested, I solved this by adding a "where ... in" clause to the class definition in the mapping file.

```
<class name="A"... where="id in (select b.id from B b where b.deleted=0)">
```